# How to Refer to Controls Created in Razor Expression?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have the following code in a View file in MVC. I'm trying to create a basic search box function. The first control is the search box, and the second is the ActionLink that I'd like to execute the search.

The ActionLink's 3rd parameter needs to be the value of the search box, so it can pass the value the user is searching for into my controller - but I can't see a way to reference the search box.

How do I refer to the search box value in this ActionLink parameter?

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <p>
        Search First and/or Last Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
        @Html.ActionLink("Search", "SearchContacts", "SearchString");
    </p>
}
```

Comment: You need to javascript in order to respond to client side events (and build a url based on the value in the textbox and use `location.href` to make your redirect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do exactly what you asked, you will need some javascript, since the value in search box is entered by the user.

But since you have a form there ( `@using (Html.BeginForm())` ) you could change the ActionLink for a submit button, something like:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SearchContacts","YourController", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Search First and/or Last Name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks Romias, that works perfectly! Better than using an ActionLink.